# Bash - argument list too long

Tags: bash, scp

I want to to `scp` from a remote server to my local computer a large folder with about 115k json files.

Let's say that I use something like this:

`scp username@remote:/remote_path/*.json /local_path/`

However when I try to do this I get the response:

`argument list too long`

How can I transfer the files then?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider transferring the whole directory instead of individual files:

```
scp -r username@remote:/remote_path /local_path/
```

If that would transfer too much and you really only want to transfer the files whose names ends with `.json` in the single directory, you may want to consider `rsync` (which has better facilities for filtering what gets transferred):

```
rsync -av --include='*.json' --exclude='*' username@remote:/remote_path/ /local_path/
```

This would only copy files whose names end in `.json` but ignore other names.  The terminating `/` on the source is needed here.

The `-a` option makes the transfer also transfer file meta data (timestamps, basically) and makes `rsync` recurse down into subdirectories (but this is restricted by `--exclude` above), while `-v` is for verbose operation.

A third option would be to create a `tar` archive of the remote directory, or at least the files that you'd want to transfer, and then `scp` that archive over to the local system.  In fact, that could be done in one go with `ssh`, simulating `scp -r`:

```
ssh username@remote 'tar -c -f - -C /remote_path .' | tar -x -f - -C /local_path
```